# Reduce number of queries made to render list of items with same in-line editable field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms, django-templates

While rendering a table of items, if the value for field X is not defined, it is rendered as a select element.

Django makes a query for each select element and these can add up and cause delays in large tables.

What is the  best way to reduce the number of queries?

**views.py**

```
from rest_framework import renderers
from rest_framework.response import Response

class ItemViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = models.Item.objects.select_related("bought_by")
  serializer_class= serializers.ItemSerializer
  filterset_fields = ("bought_by")
  renderer_classes = [renderers.JSONRenderer, renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer, renderers.TemplateHTMLRenderer]

  def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

    if request.accepted_renderer.format == "html":
      items = list()
      for item in queryset:
        items.append({"serializer": self.get_serializer(item), "item": item})


      return Response(
        {
          "items_info": items,
          "style": {"template_pack": "rest_framework/inline/"},
        },
        template_name="myapp/items_list.html",
      )
    else:
     page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
     if page is not None:
       serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
       return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

      serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**items_list.html**

```
{% load static %}
{% load rest_framework %}

{% if items_info %}
  {% csrf_token %}

  <table id="Items_Table" class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
       <th scope="col">Name</th>
       <th scope="col">Active</th>
       <th scope="col">Bought By</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      {% for pair in items_info %}

        <tr scope="row">
          <td>{{ pair.item.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ pair.item.active }}</td>
          <td>
            <form action="{{ item.url }}" method="PATCH">
            {% render_field pair.serializer.bought_by style=style %}
            </form>
          </td>
        </tr>

      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>

{% else %}
  <p class="text-center">No items to show.</p>
{% endif %}
```

If there are three items, one query each will be made to get serializer.bought_by. I thought Django/DRF would just reuse the value, but it's querying for each loop.

Trying to pass `"serializer-bought-by": self.get_serializer().bought_by` in the response, I get an `AttributeError: 'ItemSerializer' object has no attribute'bought_by'`

Printing the serializer I can see:

```
>>>print(self.get_serializer())
ItemSerializer(context={'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object>, 'format': None, 'view': <myapp.views.ItemViewSet object>}):
    url = HyperlinkedIdentityField(view_name='myapp:item-detail')
    name= CharField(unique=True, max_length=50)
    active = BooleanField(required=False)
    bought_by = SlugRelatedField(allow_null=True, queryset=<QuerySet [<Buyer: James>, <Buyer: John>, ...]>, required=False, slug_field='name')
```

Is there a way to pass the bought_by to the template?
Or do I have to use JS; render the form field outside the loop and clone/duplicate somehow?

**---Edits---**

As per Endre's request: *models.py*

```
class Buyer(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length = 20)

class Item(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length = 50)
  active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  bought_by = models.ForeignKey(Buyer, null=True, blank=True, to_field="name",)
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access the value of fields directly in the serializer. You should use `serializer.data['bought_by']` instead. Better of, don't pass the serializer to the template, instead pass the `serializer.data`. 
As for the queries in the template, no query is made to the DB to get the `bought_by` since it's already included in the serializer data. You're just showing one field name from `bought_by`, which is already preloaded in the serializer data. The `select_related` you applied also ensures that multiple queries are not made to fetch `bought_by` during serialization.

Comment: Sorry, my original question contained non-working code from an earlier version.

If I use serializer.data, I get a an `AttributeError: "noneType" object has no atribute '_field'`

The problem is not with items where a buyer is already defined, but rather with those that don't have one.  I need an HTML select that would allow the user to define one.

Comment: It's difficult to understand from this comment alone. Post a new question with the details of the new problem